# Как считать data-id у элемента?

Tags: jquery

Гружу данные методом get и "вставляю" их через $.each

```js
$.each(data.dialogs, function(){
   var html = '';
   html += '<li data-id="'+ this.id +'" class="im_dialogs">';
   html += '<a href="#'+ this.id +'">';
   html += ' <div class="dialogsEachImg"><img src="/uploads/users/'+ this.avatar +'" alt=""></div>';
   html += '<div class="dialogsEachLogin">'+ this.login +'</div>';
   html += '<div class="dialogsEachMessage">'+ this.message +'</div>';
   html += '</a>';
   html += '</li>';
   $('.dialogsEach').append(html);
});
```

`.dialogsEach` - это `<ul>`

Затем, мне нужно отследить клики по этим элементам(их может быть куча), считать data-id и передать серверу.
Проблема заключается в считывание айди, просто никак не могу.
Как я понимаю, проблема заключается в том, что из-за того, что я юзаю *append* - считывать нужно по другому(скорее всего).
Пытался найти решение в гугле, но голяк.
Выручайте.
UPD: Если указываю класс который создается динамечески, то при клике вместо заданного URL, грузится favicon.ico

Comment: Попробовал - не катит.
Если указываю класс который создается динамечески, то при клике вместо заданного URL, грузится favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Если я правельно понял вопрос.

```js
$("#addData").click(function() {
  var data = {};
  data.dialogs = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "first"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "second"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "three"
  }]


  $.each(data.dialogs, function() {
    var html = '';
    html += '<li data-id="' + this.id + '" class="im_dialogs">';
    html += this.name;
    html += '</li>';
    $('.dialogsEach').append(html);

  });

});

$(".dialogsEach").on("click", ".im_dialogs", function() {
  var x = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $("span").append(x)
})
```

```css
.im_dialogs {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addData">add Data</button>


<ul class="dialogsEach">
</ul>

<span></span>
```